# Passing Handlebars Helpers as an Argument to #if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, marionette, handlebars.js, helper

I'm using a lot of the following in my templates:

```
{{#if isController}}
```

To make that line usable, I have to serialize the data and add the isController attribute to it. Instead, I'd like to use an isController Handlebars helper.

Problem: cannot pass another helper as an argument to the #if helper.

Question: Is there a way I can pass a Handlebars helper as an argument to the #if helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.3 you can do this:

`{{outer-helper (inner-helper 'abc') 'def'}}`

More info [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/222#issuecomment-33774417)